# pnpm: What is purpose of `node_modules` in .pnpm?

Tags: npm, pnpm

I've been thinking about migration from `npm` to `pnpm`.

Before starting to migrate, I first saw [documentation(pnpm motivation)](http://pnpm.io/motivation).

There are hard link packages that point `.pnpm store(Centralized)` in `.pnpm`, and within `node_modules`, they point each package using symbolic links.

I removed `node_modules` in my project, then, I reinstalled packages using `pnpm`.
Everything seemed as I expected, except there was a `node_modules` in `.pnpm`.

What's the purpose of the `node_modules` in `.pnpm`?

What packages are there?

Answer (score 0):

To ensure sub dependency（dependency's dependency）can resolve each other,in case some package's dependency declaration forget include some sub dependency

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).